# KeyError when accessing request.POST

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I got key error in python.

error like this ..........

```
KeyError at /python_tutor/
'user_script'
```

and the code for this is

```
import web_exec
def tutor(request):
    print "Inisde tutor", request.method
    print "POST =", request.POST
    if request.method == "POST" :
        print "Inside Post"
        print "My Script =", request.POST["user_script"]
        mycode = request.POST["user_script"]
        exec mycode 
    web_exec('mycode')
```

please give me solution for this?

Comment: `exec mycode` <-- this is very, very wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`mycode = request.POST.get('user_script', None)`

Comment: 'instancemethod' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 2):

This means that the key (`user_script`) does not exist in the dictionary (`request.POST`); which suggests it's not being submitted. Try:

```
if 'user_script' in request.POST:
    print "My Script =", request.POST["user_script"]
    mycode = request.POST["user_script"]
```